# Delphi get android combobox selected item text

Tags: android, delphi, combobox, delphi-xe5

I have a combobox that has a lot of items inside and I have to get into a variable the name of the selected item.

```
var a:string;
begin
 a:=ComboBox1.Text;
end;
```

This is the way I used for a Delphi VCL application and it works. Here I'm developing with Firemonkey and Android, I haven't the `text` property.

How can I get the text of the selected item on my combobox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same way works in FireMonkey as in VCL code - use the `TComboBox.Items`. `TComboBox.ItemIndex` tells you which one is currently selected (or allows you to set the selection).

To read:

```
if ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
  ShowMessage(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]);
```

To set:

```
ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 2;
```

Comment: The code in the question hasn't necessarily been wrong in VCL applications. When `Style` is `csSimple` or `csDropDown`, what other way is there to determine the text when the text has been typed in and doesn't match any item in the list? FireMonkey lacks a `Style` property, and apparently lacks an editable combo box entirely.

Answer (score 8):

you can access the Selected property to get text :

```
 if ComboBox1.ItemIndex >= 0 then
    ShowMessage(ComboBox1.Selected.Text);
```